# Is it possible use a custom script to compile code eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want compile my project using a `.sh` file. Now every time, I open my terminal, I go to my project's folder and run sh `build.sh` (it is the script with `g++` etc etc)

How can I use the sh file inside eclipse?? Is it possible?

Comment: You can create a makefile project and change settings to call your script instead of `make`.

Answer (score 4):

Open your project properties and select "C/C++ Build". Under the "Builder Settings" tab, select "External builder" in the "Builder type:" dropdown. Uncheck "Use default build command", and then enter your script name in "Build command:". That should do it.